# URL is getting displayed as String in table

Tags: java, string, url

I wanted to display one URL in a table.

Value I had was : www.yahoo.com

I converted into format as below and returning back to table  :

```
<a href="<font color="red">www.yahoo.com</font>"> Link </a>
```

I want it to be displayed in URL form. But it is displaying as a string like as it is above.

Below is the method used for conversion :

```
private static String validateString(String header) throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&& inside validateString ");
    String displayString = "";
    String colorValue = "";

    try
    {
        if((header) != null && !"null".equalsIgnoreCase(header))
        {
            displayString = header;


                colorValue = "red";
                displayString = "<font color=\""+colorValue+"\">"+displayString+"</font>";

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            displayString = "&nbsp;";
    }

    if(!"".equals(displayString))
    {
            displayString = "<a href=\""+displayString+"\"> Link </a>";
    }

    if ("".equals(displayString))
    {
        displayString = "&nbsp;";
    }

    return displayString;
}
```

Please let me know how to display as URL.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget to wrap it all inside `<html></html>`?

Comment: The  quotation marks in <a href="<font color="red">www.yahoo.com</font>"> Link </a> are misplaced. This can't work!

Comment: Can you let me know what should be the exact format please.

Comment: Use single quotations like <a href="<font color='red'>www.yahoo.com</font>">

Comment: Again...the HREF property is not the place to add style properties, use the style attribute instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the attribute href for the tag A, you only should use the proper URL not ant other tag. Change it to something like this:

```
<a href="www.yahoo.es" style="color: red">Link</a>
```

Comment: @MirandaVeracruzDeLaHoyaCardina you just CAN NOT use a tag font inside the href attribute